# Missing wildcard in checkpoint rule - Snakemake

Tags: workflow, snakemake

I have a checkpoints that leads to an unknown number of files, needing DAG reevaluation after execution. I wanted to speed it up by parallelizing the command by chromosome. Thus, after reevaluating, I would merge all chromosomes by experiment. However, snakemake is unable to infere the chromosomes.

```
checkpoint GenomeAnalysisTK:
    input:
        bamlist = rules.RealignerTargetCreator.output.bamlist,
        intervals = rules.RealignerTargetCreator.output.intervals,
        fasta = fasta
    output:
        temp(directory("splits/{chromosome}"))
    conda:
        "gatk3"
    wildcard_constraints:
            chromosome='|'.join([x for x in detect_chromosomes(fai)]),
    shell:
        """
        mkdir -p {output} && cd {output}
        gatk3 -Xmx24g -T IndelRealigner -I {input.bamlist} -targetIntervals {input.intervals} -L {wildcards.chromosome} -R {input.fasta} -compress 0 --nWayOut .{wildcards.chromosome}.indelrealigned.bam 
        """


def agg(wildcards):
    output=checkpoints.GenomeAnalysisTK.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    return expand("splits/{chromosome}/{{experiment}}/{chromosome}.indelrealigned.bam")

rule merge_realigned:
    input:
        agg
    output:
        "{patient}/{sample}/{experiment}.merged.indelrealigned.bam"
    threads:
        config["other_threads"],
    params:
        compression_level = 0
    wildcard_constraints:
            chromosome='|'.join([x for x in detect_chromosomes(fai)]),
    shell:
        "samtools merge -@ {threads} -l {params.compression_level} {output} {input}"
```

However, I get the typical "WorkflowError: Missing wildcard values for chromosome". How can I make it infere the chromosomes?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `merge_realigned` rule doesn't have a wildcard for chromosome to match, so you have to specify it in the input function.  However, your rule depends on all chromosomes, so you have to get the outputs of all chromosomes first:

```
def agg(wildcards):
    for chrom in CHROMSOME_LIST:
        checkpoints.GenomeAnalysisTK.get(chromosome=chrom, **wildcards).output
    return expand("splits/{chromosome}/{{experiment}}/{chromosome}.indelrealigned.bam",
       chromosome=CHROMOSOME_LIST)
```

and you also have to specify the chromosomes in your expand statement.

The for loop construct may prevent parallel execution if the first checkpoint must complete before requesting the second, I'm not positive this is the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I did try something similar but indeed there is no parallel execution. I had to change the implementation because there is no way snakemake can interpret the chromosome wildcard.

For those wondering, I split the file by chromosomes in the beginning of the DAG, then run intermediate rules if needed, and then I gather everything with a rule using a `expand()`. I don't like that additional step, but it's the only way I found to make it work properly.